# When I shut the bike down there is horrible fuel smell

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, carburetor, harley-davidson

2003 Harley-Davidson FXDL.

After I shut it off, I get this horrible fuel smell. The bike has Mikuni 42 carburetor, Pingel shutoff valve, carburetor rebuilt, Pingel holding strong. I do not have the charcoal evaporation canister on.

Is there a way to diminish this problem? Neighbors are complaining.

Comment: By `horrible fuel smell` do you mean just the smell of gasoline, the smell of burnt gasoline, or what?

Comment: Is that year DYNA using a mechanical or a vacuum shut off for the fuel.

Comment: If it is fresh gas smell and strong enough for places near you to smell it, you have a leak or a float issue.  The leak can be found with fingers and paper towels looking for wetness.    Is the tank the saddle over the frame with a cross over line (good place not to see a leak)?    Was the Pingel added to fix issue or for more fuel?